# Roscore on android device

Tags: roscore, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is it posible to run roscore on an android device, and make other nodes on a ubuntu laptop connect to it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59319/roscore-on-android-device/) by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's possible to run the roscore on the Android device.  You can start one programmatically using `RosCore.newPublic()` which will listen on the public interfaces.  (The `MasterChoooser` default implementation will start a Private server, not accessible by the outside world).

Once you start your RosCore, you can set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` environment variable on your Ubuntu laptop to your Android device: `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`

Once that is set (in all your shells), you should be able to see topics using `rostopic` and the other basic tools.

---

Originally posted by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) with karma: 218 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on 2013-03-27**:
Thank you very much for your answer. I will give it a try.